# Spark Cassandra CassandraSourceRelation directJoinSetting exception error

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-cassandra-connector

```
    

    // Input Identifiers
    val ids = List("4723847392423894", "4329479647236423", "42348726782684")


    import spark.implicits._
    val settings = Map("table" -> "table_name", "keyspace" -> "keyspace_name")
    val tableDF = spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(settings).load()
    val idsListDF = ids.asInstanceOf[List[String]].toDF("id").persist()
    idsListDF.join(tableDF, tableDF.col("id") === idsListDF.col("id"), "inner").persist()
```

**Exception**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSourceRelation.directJoinSetting()Lorg/apache/spark/sql/cassandra/DirectJoinSetting;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.execution.CassandraDirectJoinStrategy$.containsSafePlans(CassandraDirectJoinStrategy.scala:333)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.execution.CassandraDirectJoinStrategy$.validJoinBranch(CassandraDirectJoinStrategy.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.execution.CassandraDirectJoinStrategy.rightValid(CassandraDirectJoinStrategy.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.execution.CassandraDirectJoinStrategy.hasValidDirectJoin(CassandraDirectJoinStrategy.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.execution.CassandraDirectJoinStrategy.apply(CassandraDirectJoinStrategy.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:63)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:435)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:441)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
```

Could you please help me with what's wrong with the code?

I have tried the `directJoin(Automatic)` automatic, always, always off but still no luck

```
idsListDF.join(tableDF.directJoin(Automatic), tableDF.col("batch_id") === idsListDF.col("id"), "inner").persist()
```

FYI - I'm using the Spark Cassandra connector jar - https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector

Comment: What's the Spark version + connector version you're using?

Comment: spark version is - 2.4.4 and spark Cassandra connector is 2.5.1

Comment: Use proper combination of spark/scala-cassandra version. check version compatibility here - https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector#version-compatibility

Comment: Yes i'm using right version only ```<dependency>
   <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.11</artifactId>
   <version>2.5.1</version>
  </dependency>```

Comment: some spark Cassandra connector old version jar has been added into the spark jar folder so it was causing that issue.  don't know who added that jar into spark jar folder.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an environmental issue although I'm unable to pinpoint the cause.

I've engaged the Analytics team here at DataStax and I will post an update once I get a response. Cheers!

P.S. Thanks for posting the Spark + connector versions. I'd recommend updating your original question with those details to make it easier for other contributors to help you.